# Integration of a vector return one value

Tags: r

I am using R to do some multivariate analysis. For this work I need to integrate the trivariate PDF.Since I want to use this in a MLE, a want a vector of integration. Is there a way to make `Integrate`bring a vector instead of one value.

Here is simple example:

```
f1=function(x, y, z) {dmvnorm(x=as.matrix(cbind(x,y,z)), mean=c(0,0,0), sigma=sigma)}
f1(x=c(1,1,1), y=c(1,1,1), z=c(1,1,1))
integrate(Vectorize(function(x) {f1(x=c(1,1,1), y=c(1,1,1), z=c(1,1,1))}), lower = -   Inf, upper = -1)$value

Error in integrate(Vectorize(function(x) { : evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

Comment: What is the value of `sigma`? (Perhaps just `diag(3)`)

Comment: yeah. It is 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Do you just want to sum over the resulting vector?

Comment: After taking the logs of each integration, yeah.

Comment: Would `integrate(Vectorize(function(x) {sum(log(f1(x=c(1,1,1), y=c(1,1,1), z=c(1,1,1))))}), lower = -   Inf, upper = -1)$value` work?

Comment: I think it would be more like, sum(log(integrate(Vectorize(function(x) {f1(x=c(1,1,1), y=c(1,1,1), z=c(1,1,1))}), lower = - Inf, upper = -1)$value))

Comment: In your example, the function you are integrating is constant.
If you want to integrate `dmvnorm` (that is a triple integral -- 
`integrate` only integrates univariate functions),
it is already there: `pmvnorm`.

Comment: Vincent, I need to intengrate once, twice and three time. The Three times I am aware of using pmvnorm, but for the other cases I had failed to get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate a function of one variable, with vector values,
you can transform the function into n functions with real values, 
and integrate each of them. 
This is very inefficient (when integrating the i-th function, 
I evaluate all the functions, and discard all but one value).

```
# Function to integrate
d <- rnorm(10)
f <- function(x) dnorm(d, mean=x)

# Integrate those n functions separately.
n <- length(f(1))
r <- sapply( 1:n, 
  function(i) integrate( 
    Vectorize(function(x) f(x)[i]), 
    lower=-Inf, upper=0 
  )$value 
)
r
```

For 2-dimensional integrals, you can check `pracma::integral2`,
but the same manipulation (transforming a bivariate function with vector values 
into n bivariate functions with real values) will probably be needed.