# R, Integrate an array of functions with multiple integration bounds

Tags: arrays, r, integrate

I'm stuck with computing an integral in R. Suppose I have some function:

```
SomeFun = function(x) {x*parameter}
```

Now, `parameter` need not be a scalar. It may be a matrix (e.g. a `(2 x 2)` matrix).
Hence, if I input a scalar-valued `x` my function returns a `(2 x 2)` matrix.

**Now my question**: Is it possible to compute the definite integral of `SomeFun` where each element of the matrix has different upper and lower bounds? Something like:

```
integrate(SomeFun, lower=c(0,2,0,-1), upper=c(1,5,1,1))
```

Hence, I get a `(2 x 2)` matix of definite integrals where the first entry (upper left corner) is integrated between 0 and 1 whereas the last entry (lower right) is integrated between -1 and 1.

**Thank you very much for your comments. Romain**

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16069977/1129973

Comment: You can also see `library(cubature);adaptIntegrate(...)`